# Variable reference scope

Tags: php, pass-by-reference

```
class A {
  public $o;
  function __construct(&$o) {
    $this->o = $o;
  }
  function set($v) {
    $this->o["foo"] = $v;
  }
}

$o = ["hello" => "world"];
$a = new A($o);
$a->set(1);

echo json_encode($a->o)  // { "hello": "world", "foo": 1 }
echo json_encode($o)  // { "hello": "world" }
```

What must I do to have output #2 be like output #1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using reference argument is not enough. You need to set your `$this->o` to an actual reference to `$o`:

```php
$this->o = &$o;
```

Comment: Do you know of any documentation where to read up on the subject?

Comment: I'd explore https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.references.php, especially the comments.

Answer (score 1):

You must specify a reference to parameter in constructor when you pass value to the variable.

```
function __construct(&$o) {
  $this->o = &$o;
}
```

Output:

```
echo json_encode($a->o);  // { "hello": "world", "foo": 1 }
echo json_encode($o);  // { "hello": "world", "foo":1 }
```